# Extracting isxdl.dll from the setup takes a long time

Tags: performance, inno-setup

I'm using InnoSetup to create an installer for my WPF application. My application is about ~300Mo.
I've implemented this method to check if the client environment has MS Framework 4.0:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup
This method uses the isxdl.dll.

When I start the installer, it stuck 10 seconds on this task (in InnoSetup debug mode):

```
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\is-IKJ7C.tmp\isxdl.dll
```

This DLL is about 122Ko, that's light.
I've tried to create the same installer (using the same scripts) with a lighter application (about 5Mo), and the installer works well (no more stuck time).

I do not know how it is possible that the application files (the weight of the application) affect the loading of this dll.

Comment: Do you use `SolidCompression`? Does `isdxdl.dll` is the first file in `[Files]` section? All files that are required by installer script should be placed on the beginning of the `[Files]` section. It's also good idea to use `Flags: nocompression` for these files (can go along with `dontcopy`)

Comment: I was using SolidCompression. The problem is solved after removing it. Thank a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All files that are going to be used by Install Script for actions & functions should be placed at the beginning of `[Files]` section especially when using `SolidCompression=True`. It's also good option to use `Flags: nocompression dontcopy` for them.

```
[Files]
Source: ".\ISWin7.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy nocompression
Source: ".\games\{#BMPDir}\BMP\*"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy nocompression
Source: ".\InnoCallback.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy nocompression
Source: ".\MyAppSourceFiles\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

> The disadvantage to using solid compression is that because all files
>   are compressed into a single compressed stream, Setup can no longer
>   randomly access the files

- that makes it to "unpack all files" before it can access the last one. More info [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_solidcompression).